# ${}$What is an electron?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, electrons, atomic-physics, wave-particle-duality

I have been taught that an electron has a wave-particle duality nature and an electron behaves as a wave when traveling.

I do also know that a wave is some kind of vibration, either it be a vibration of a vector field, or of a particle.

My questions is: If an electron behaves as a wave and a wave means some sort of vibrations, then what "kind" of vibration is/describes an electron?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is an Electron?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/95503/)

Comment: I am not exactly meant " what is an electron". The last para in the question explains my doubt. I am asking about one of its properties-The "type" of vibration associated with it.

Comment: [An electron is a vibration in the electron field](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/118927/123208)

Answer (score 1):

Questions like that are not easy to answer, since the electron is nothing which one can compare to a thing which is understood by something more intuitive to you without making unwanted simplifications. 
When someone asks me a question like that i would say something like:

```
                     An electron is the sum of its properties.
```

So it is something which is interacting via its electric charge its spin (which could be understood like a magnetic dipole moment) its isospin (which is something like the charge of the weak interaction). It has the mass $m_e$.

It can be described as a wave and as a particle, dependent on the energy scale on which it is observed.

The most "complete" description of the electron is given by the [Dirac-Field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermionic_field).

Comment: so in accordance with the Dirac-field theory, what type of vibration is associated with an electron?

Comment: is it an electric field??

Comment: What is an electric field to your understanding ?